# Java check if parameter contains vowels

Tags: java

I am kind of new to Java coming from a JavaScript background. I am trying to check if a given parameter contains vowels and if so, return true. This is what I have so far:

```
public class StringUtils {      
  public static boolean isVowel(String s) {
  String x = s.toLowerCase();
    if(x.indexOf('a' || 'e' || 'i' || 'o' || 'u')) {
      return true;
    } else {
      return false;
    }
  }
}
```

How should this be done in Java?

Comment: `x.indexOf('a') || x.indexOf('e')...`

Comment: You can use regex, as well, check out [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/)

Comment: I am curious , why he got so many negative votings for a valid question ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try this method to check for vowels:

```
public static boolean isVowel(char c) {
  return "AEIOUaeiou".indexOf(c) != -1;
}
```

You can try regex also:

```
yourString.matches("[AEIOUaeiou]")
```

smth like that